# Обход лицензии QtWebEngine

Tags: лицензирование, qtwebengine

изучаю модуль Qt Web Engine был неприятно удивлен тем, что тот просто не отображался в библиотеках, почитал, сначала подумал дело в том, что забыл в установщике поставить галку загрузки данного модуля, переустановил и ничего, потом подумал дело в MinGw запустил на MSVC и тоже ничего, тогда уже вычитал в онлайн установщике что на данный модуль накладывается доп лицензия LGPLv2.1 не подскажите как ее обойти? Искал в инете гайд обхода, но нигде не информации, помогите

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы имеете в виду под "обойти"? LGPL всего лишь лицензия для библиотек, она никак не влияет на работоспособность какой-либо программы, это ведь только текст.

Comment: Так дело в том, что Qt не видит данную библиотеку, а на на добавления модуля веб ингайна в файл про, пишет что не знает название такого модуля

Comment: Я кажись понял в чем дело, у Qt есть такое понятие как комметрческий продукт и продукт с открытым исходным кодом и кажись я скачал версию коммерческую , в этом причина, щас буду проверять, точнее завтра когда уже переустановлю

Comment: Хм, тогда это имеет больше смысла. Похоже, что именно в этом и причина, так как `GPL` подобные лицензии требуют открытого читаемого исходного кода. Спасибо за информацию!

Comment: Безрезультатно, не работает, на сайте толком не понятно какую еще лиценцию,кроме LGPLv3 получает пользователь при откром исходном коде, очень много лишней воды из за чего становится ничего не понятно